# Qt - change QWidget layout

Tags: qt, layout, qt4, qwidget

Let's consider we have a `QWidget` and a `QLayout` named `general_layout` that contains other widgets and layouts. `general_layout` is set as the `QWidget` layout like this:

```
setLayout(general_layout)
```

Now I should to change the content of `QWidget`. How can I do that? I have tried to delete and create a new layout for the `QWidget` and that new layout set as a layout of the `QWidget`, but could not complete my intentions successfully.

This is my code:

```
delete general_layout;
general_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
general_layout->addLayout(some_layout);
myQWidget->setLayout(general_layout);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? What you are doing seems to be correct (ie delete old layout before setting a new one).

Comment: Sure! I do the following:

delete general_layout;
general_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
general_layout->addLayout(some_layout);
myQWidget->setLayout(general_layout);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the widgets of a layout are not destroyed when deleting a layout. This results in all child widgets of myQWidget still being present, be it without a layout.

The solution is simple: add a

```
qDeleteAll(myQWidget->children());
```

after

```
delete general_layout;
```

Comment: Seems that was the problem. Thanks a lot!!! Just one more question too. I want to have a dialog that changes its structure (in the aspect of this question). So I do that with creating layout, deleting and creating a new one. Is that a good approach?

Comment: Could be if you don't need the first structure anymore. If you do, using QStackedLayout (http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qstackedlayout.html) is much easier.
If you're trying to implement something like a wizard, take a look at QWizard (http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwizard.html).

Comment: qDeleteAll(myQWidget->children()); function deletes all childs, but what about child of the childs. I mean within the child elements of myQWidget there are no layouts which are child layout of general_layout. When I call a method of a child layout of general_layout, my application blows up (so I guest that pointer is destroyed), but when I check if it equals to 0 (m_childLayout_of_General_Layout == 0), then if statement is ignored. What's the matter? Is it deleted or no?

Comment: Yes, all children (direct or indirect) are deleted (take a look at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#dtor.QObject).
In C++, calling delete on a pointer does not set this pointer to 0. That's why your if-statement does not work.
As I said before, if you still need the old widgets, using a QStackedLayout might be the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps you should be making the child widgets children of the layout they are in, as opposed to their logical grandparent?